# I included `SDL_TTF.h`. What else should I do to SDT true type font working?

Tags: c++, sdl

I have been following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZVk7N8eUjsc) but keep getting

> **error LNK1104: cannot open file 'SDL_ttf.lib'**

I have download SDL 1.2.15 
and added SDL2_ttf 2.0.12

I am using every thing in this tutorial and many more things I found but nothing is helping.I think there is some problem in mt visual studio but I am not sure.

Please tell me what could possibly be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, why are you mixing SDL 1.2 with SDL 2.0? Stick with the new SDL 2.0.
Once you download and set SDL 2.0 up, include `<SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>` and link with -lSDL2_ttf.

I highly recommend you [this](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/index.php) tutorial by LazyFoo, it is extremely clear.